# Check if more than 3 hours

Tags: calculated-column

I need a calculated column to display "Yes" if the current time is more than 3 hours after the value of another column. This is what I've come up with:

```
=TEXT(Today-[AddTime],"h")>3
```

But SP tells me this is invalid. Are there other ways of doing this?

Larsi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you google around for this you are going to come across pages telling you you can do this with calculated columns using the [Today] trick.

You can't, it [doesn't work and isn't updated dynamically](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+truth+about+today) - and even if it were [Today] doesn't include a time component so X hrs is out.

A couple of options for you

- Use a [CEWP and JavaScript](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2011/01/18/live-demo-countdowncountup/) to modify
  the display to show your Yes/No
  column.
- [Create a custom dataview
  usign SharePoint Designer/XSLT](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/05/sharepoint-designer-article-2-creating.html).
- Use
  [Workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010100587.aspx) to run a job X hours after
  your record has been inserted to
  change the Yes/No column.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx), it's a good primer for calculated columns.  Also, Today and Me are not allowed in calculated columns.

Comment: Handy link, I've included it in the tag wiki (to be approved): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/calculated-column/info

Answer (score 2):

Excuse my self-promotion, but:

We've developed a custom column that can do just that, which is currently in Public Beta: http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/highlighter/beta-testers-guide

To set it up to do this, you'd choose:

- Highlighting
- Display: Cell highlighting
- Rules: Click "Add custom", then add the following two rules:

[image: Rules example]

Answer (score -1):

This can likely be implemented not in a calculated column but in a computed column. The difference being that a calculated column is only calculated during edits, and a computed column for each render.

Wouter

Comment: I'm curious as to how one would implement a custom Computed column at all, to be honest. I was under the impression you'd have to inherit from SPFieldComputed, which is uninheritable.

Comment: You don't develop a computed column, you only configure it. E.g. <Field Type="Computed"> and then use the render pattern to define the UI

Comment: Oh, I understand. However, you don't have to use Computed in that instance, and I haven't come across a calculation-friendly version of ThreadStamp in the View Schema so far.